# What should we call our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Since I can, because I am me and I can... Ok, now seriously. :P

I have the privileges to change the chat room name and description, so let's propose new names! Consider that you should:

- Propose a name (possibly explain why that name);
- And a description if you want, even if maybe we can keep this one since it points to the main site.

In any case, **provide one per answer**, so other people can vote on a single proposal. :)

Please use Mochan's answer format to keep consistency.

Comment: If the Durarara! chatroom had a name, it would've been perfect. Does anyone remember any scene where a name or a website address is shown?

Comment: @Fadeway I don't understand your comment... What do you mean? :P

Comment: DRRR is one of the only shows where the characters actually use the Internet, and their use of an anonymous chatroom is often shown. If that chatroom had a name (I don't recall, hence I can't post an answer), I'm dropping this off as an idea in case anyone knows it, as it would be a strong contestant.

Comment: @Fadeway Ah! Nice idea. :D

Comment: @Fadeway I think it was just called The Dollars Chatroom or something

Comment: I think the name shouldn't be anime-specific unless the anime is really that famous. Otherwise it might become a contest between which anime has more fans in this meta.

Comment: Shouldn't it be called something like  Konoha? It's full if naruto fanboys, most of the questions naruto / bleach / one piece related...

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to go off the beaten path and suggest the obvious:

**Name:** Anime and Manga Chat

My personal pet peave is looking through the list of chat rooms and having absolutely no idea what half of them are about. Why obfuscate your chat room behind a list of clever in-jokes and memes? Seems counter-productive. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: Eheh they don't need to be *obscure*... And probably shouldn't be. But peculiar? That's not a bad thing to me. But as you hinted, it's probably a matter of preference (that's why I'm surveying in the first place).

Comment: I go agree leaving it simple for now is the best option. Maybe when this SE graduates, we can have another vote for a classier name? Like SciFi.SE's Mos Eisley.

Comment: @Krazer I don't see the difference in doing it now or after graduation?

Comment: @Alenanno Diversity. More ppl, more ideas, better consensus.

Comment: Thanks for making this answer. I thought I was the only one who would prefer leaving it as something obvious, but now it's quite obvious that I'm far from alone.

Comment: @Krazer Ah I see. I didn't get the comment notification... weird. :P

Comment: @atlantiza Why didn't you propose it? :P

Answer (score 4):

**Name:** Akiba

**Description:** Meet up at the Electric Town. (any suggestion is welcomed, a smart quote about Akiba would be perfect)

**Explanation:** As Wikipedia, "major shopping area for electronic, computer, anime, and otaku goods". It's a suggestive place for everyone is interested in anime and manga subculture, JNTO put this place at the top of their [Japan Anime Map](http://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/animemap/index.html), calling it "sacred land of the otaku legions". This contraption of [Akihabara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akihabara) is used frequently in anime and manga (e.g. *Densha Otoko*) and it's more simple than the long form. Could a word by 5 letters be more meaningful?

Answer (score 3):

**Name:** "Cat's Eye"

**Origin:** The name originates from a cafe reoccurs in many series drawn and authored by Tsukasa Hojo (Originated in Cat's Eye, reoccurs in City Hunter and Angel Heart). The cafe is run by a trio of sister that moonlight as art thieves under the name of "[Cat's Eye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_Eye_(manga))." A reference to this is also made in Clamp's Tsubasa Chronicles.

**Reasoning:** The cafe recurs in many anime and manga universes, so it seems like a good place to mingle and talk about various anime and manga. My first choice would probably have been "[Ahnenerbe](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ahnenerbe)" from the Type-Moon metafiction, it's also a cafe shop with two entrances located beside a cinema or large bridge, and it exists in multiple locations across multiple meta-universes. Here various characters from the Type-Moon universe can meet people that they would not otherwise be able to without causing inconsistencies in the workings of either world of timeline (E.g., Shiki from *Tsukihime* and Shiki from *Kara no Kyoukai*). I wound up not choosing "Ahnenerbe" because of it's negative relation with [Nazi culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahnenerbe).

[image: Because (White) Mokona said so!]

Comment: Ah... what a pity, I would have loved "Ahnenerbe"!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is 3-4 years late and many things changed since the context of the question, but...

**Keep the same name and description**.

---

> [Maid Café (メイド喫茶)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-)
>
> *Welcome back, my Master! (お帰りなさいませ、ご主人様!) Sit wherever you'd like and enjoy some General Chat for anime.stackexchange.com. Now serving anime and manga images in regular intervals via our maid service. To learn more about our maid service, please visit: meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/1166/191*

We, as a community, have been always using the same name. New friends and a whole new story were built using that name. It's almost an traditional and it carries a whole human value with it. It's *neccessary* to keep it? No, sure no. We'll still  chat and have fun together. But, as a tradition, it's cool to keep it. It's an *identity* thing.

The term *Maid café* also says a lot about the chat organization. It remembers the culture that's related to the community not only in the chat but in the main Q&A site too - the japanese culture. With our bots (our *"maids"*), we get served with what we want and what we need. It's complete by itself.

It also says a lot about us because we're just like a Maid Café: you can just pull a chair and enjoy stuff you like with nice people. It's inviting. You can feel like there are some jokes in the air and there are people who will interact with you.

More over, Maid cafés are not limited to anime only, which is exactly like us. There are a lot of programmers in the chat and game fans, so random subjects just pop and we can talk about them without worrying if that's part of the *chat* or not. C'mon, chat's are made to chat!

And, above anything, we, as a community, have been always using this name. New friends and a whole new story were built using it. It's almost an traditional and it carries a whole human value with it. It's *neccessary* to keep it? No, it's not. We'll still  chat and have fun together. But, as a tradition, it's cool to keep it. It's an *identity* thing. **We are the *Maid Café*** . :)

Comment: Things were quite different back in beta. "Maid Cafe" was a [2013 decision](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/789/2014-edition-what-should-we-call-our-chat-room/790#790) btw.

Answer (score -1):

- **Name**
  *Anime Amour and Manga Madness*
- **Description**
  For those wishing to discuss their favourite anime and manga, and to socialize with people who enjoy what you do!
- **Explanation**
  Amour means 'love' or 'romance'. I'd say I'm fairly in love with anime... and I'm mad about manga, too :)

Answer (score -1):

**Name:** The Boundary of the Ethereal Horizon (不可視境界線の境界, Fukashi Kyoukaisen no Kyoukai)

**Description:** General discussion for [anime.stackexchange.com](http://anime.stackexchange.com). Blast reality! Burst into shreds! Banishment... this world!
[anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) [chuunibyou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chuunibyou) [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga)

---

The name was changed again to this as of Dec. 29nd, 2013. In an effort to promote more attention on a chat room name.* If you have a better name suggestion, please post it in the thread and the community will vote on it!

In the words of the Dark Flame Master.... **Perish, enveloped in the flames of darkness!**

*<sub>Does not mean the discussion on this matter is closed. If better proposals arise and the community approves, the name and description can be changed.</sub>*

Comment: Could we maybe start a new question for figuring out the room name? It seems to me clear that as of a year ago, the consensus was strongly to keep it "Anime & Manga Chat". Since then there have been a few complaints, but it would be much better if we could get an idea of what current chat users really want. If there are good suggestions here they can be copied there, but I'm getting a bit confused trying to read this question with all the year-old suggestions and votes.

Answer (score -2):

Here's another idea I had:

**Name:** Speech Bubbles

Can't think of an apt description, though.

Answer (score -2):

- **Name:**
  *Wide eyes*
- **Description:**
  The place to discuss anime and manga!

I'm not sure about the description, but I'm sure everyone gets the name!
And yes, I know not every anime/manga uses wide-eyed characters. :D

Comment: Ahah wide eyes... :D

Comment: This is just my opinion but I think naming the chat room using a random anime trope is rather arbitrary. I'd prefer either Mochan's name that refers to the topics of discussion, or my own names that connect to the idea of "chatting".

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps a play on a major council or chatroom from an anime?

- From Eva: Human Instrumentality Committee (or SEELE)

I'd propose something from Naruto, but haven't actually watched the series.

Answer (score -2):

- **Name:** 
  The Guardians
- **Description:** 
  Guardians of earth united to protect ALL the people from ALL the evil.

For sure the ALL's can be removed, but it comes a bit geeky.

Answer (score -3):

- **Name**
  Spiky hairs *(or something like that)*
- **Description**
  Because 99% of anime characters have spiky hair.

Answer (score -3):

**Name**:
Ahnenerbe

**Explanation**:
Ahnenerbe is, in the Type-Moon fandom, the cafe where characters from different franchises meet to speak to each other and explain aspects of the story.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahnenerbe

Comment: I wonder what Nasu was thinking when he chose the name. Anyway, rather more relevant, http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ahnenerbe

Answer (score -3):

- **Name:**  C.H.A.T.  -> Cyber Haven for Anime Talk
- **Description:** Cyber Haven for Anime Talk, it'll be a play on the word chat itself.
- **Explanation:** Well, the room will be a haven for anime lovers, and things relating to anime and it's in cyberspace.

What do you think? It'll be neutral to both seasoned anime lovers and newcomers but has a dash of "cyberpunk love" in the name (or so my mind is leading me to perceive :P  )

Answer (score -4):

**Name:** SFX

**Description:** For background sounds and chatter that may fall outside the main panels of the Q&A!

*Translator's note: Ok, this was a little tongue-in-cheek so I'm ok with editing the description to fit more to the community's taste.*

Comment: Why SFX? I don't get the joke. :D

Comment: SFX stands for "special effects", or the background noises usually depicted by katakana or hiragana in manga. This includes the "don-don-don" of knocking on doors, "doki-doki" of frantic heartbeats, or even "hahahaha~". These sound cues help to express situations, and they are best known as "SFX".

Comment: Yes, I know what SFX refers to, but I couldn't link to the Anime/Manga world... Now I can, thanks. :D