# What should our "unofficial" community name and logo or mascot be?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Since we are looking to expand our social circles I think we should have a name for our unofficial SE community. We can change it later on down the like, but I think we should have something that identifies us as a community.

I'd like like to ask for everyone's idea of what our community name and logo should be and look like. The logo does not need to be the finished product. A rough sketch in paint is fine. I'll work with the author of the top rated answer to create a more polished product.

**If you want to just propose a name or logo, that's fine as well.**

Remember to follow these copyright guidelines when creating the name and logo:

- Do not use Stack Exchange's logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange, Inc.
- Do not use Stack Exchange's name or logo in a way that might imply a false sense of partnership or endorsement with your product.
- Do not use any name or logo that is similar to or might be confused with Stack Exchange's name or logo.
- Do not distort or alter Stack Exchange's logo in any way.
- Do not use our Stack Exchange's logo in a way that confuses our brand with another brand.
- Do not use any Stack Exchange artwork from their network without explicit permission.

Don't forget to upvote the answers you like and leave any comments or critiques for the authors.

If possible, use this format:

> **Name**: *[Insert name proposal here]*
>
> **Reasoning**: *[Insert name proposal reasoning here]*
>
> or
>
> **Tagline**: *[Insert tagline proposal here]*

(and/or)

> **Logo**: *[Insert logo image concept, if applicable]*
>
> *[Insert brief summary of the reasoning behind the concept]*

(and/or)

> **Mascot Name**: *[Insert name of mascot]*
>
> *[Insert brief summary of the reasoning behind the concept]*
>
> *[Insert rough concept, if applicable]*

Comment: Should any suggestions have *both* a name and a logo? (i.e. What do we do it we can think of a logo but not a name, or vice-versa?)

Comment: You can post either one or both.

Comment: Just wanted to drop a quick note saying if you're creating this "unofficial" community identity because of traditions in anime culture, that's great and carry on. If you're doing it because you think you *have* to in order to comply with our trademark guidance on any social media pages you create, that's not exactly true. You can title pages something like "Anime & Manga Stack Exchange Community" and otherwise make it clear that the pages are not run by SE the company, and that's sufficient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my proposal for the community logo. I did it in the style of the Japanese *mon* (family emblems):

This typographic logo uses the stylized kanji for `画`:

[image: :)]

Comment: This looks rather good. Were you thinking of keeping it always white-on-black, or stylizing it at all?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions

Comment: This is great! It is clean and can have some interesting variations in colour, depending on the contexts it is used.

Comment: What is the meaning of the kanji?

Comment: @xjshiya: read this: https://www.facebook.com/AnimeAndMangaQA/posts/556218247744619

Answer (score 11):

I suggest that we create a mascot-character, similar to [Wikipe-tan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikipe-tan) or the [OS-tans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-tan). Our logo should be designed to incorporate that character. This is a pretty common thing on anime-themed websites, though it's certainly not universal. I thought about drawing something myself, but my artwork is worse than Kobayashi Yuu's drawings, so I'm not the best choice.

Comment: I like this idea. We can call her Sachi-tan or something and play it like those after show segments like "Kero's Corner" in CCS. We could call it "Ask Sachi" or something.

Comment: How about something like an anime tenchou?

Comment: @Krazer Am I missing something? Why do you want to call her Sachi? lol

Answer (score 4):

**Name:** Ayama

**Reasoning:** Taken from the first *kana* of each word in the Japanese translation of "Anime and Manga" (アニメやまんが -> アやま -> *Ayama*). It's short, easy to remember, and unique to us.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this can be written as 謝, 誤, or 過, meaning (respectively) "apology", "mistake", and "error" (though there are more neutral ways to write it as well such as 逢山, meaning "rendezvous mountain").

Comment: @LoganM Yes, though usually it would have okurigana (る, り, つ, ち, etc.) after it. I can't think of a context where you'd ever see any of those three symbols written alone. (Though in pronunciation you are correct. Japanese is full of puns.)

Answer (score 2):

Name: (Unofficial) Anime & Manga Stack Exchange Community

Reasoning: Probably any otaku-based nickname we can think of will be an already overused term for other communities and it will be unclear that our group has anything to do with any SE. Why not just keep it simple so people know what they're looking at?

Answer (score 1):

**Name:** "Ask Anime & Manga"

**Reasoning:**: Got an itching Anime and/or Manga question? We'll try to answer it for you!

Comment: It almost sounds like you are actually asking a TV show or book rather than a group of people lol

Answer (score -3):

**Name**: (unofficial) "Akihabara" or "Akiba"

**Reasoning**: As per [this answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/205/189) for chat, it's the "sacred land of the otaku legions."  Fitting, appropriate, and if you're part of the group, you can easily recognize it.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this idea. The name is pretty overused among western anime communities as-is, and it already has another meaning in common parlance. We don't just want things that are anime specific, we want something that will be Anime.SE-specific.