# List of icons/symbols we'd like to see in our repeating background pattern

Tags: discussion, design

There are a number of SE sites which have some relevant to the topic of the site icons, symbols and graphics in the header or the repeating background pattern. I'm not exactly sure how much our designers are in on the anime topic, but just to give them some ideas, I'd like to compile a list of things that our community thinks are, if not stereotypically representative, then at least noteworthy, and should be included or used as a reference for symbols in our site's theme.

[Movies&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) has posterized iconic imagery from well known movies, so I guess it's not out of the question to have basically the same type of deal here, but in a different style of execution. Like a background pattern of iconic imagery, as I'm suggesting.

Some anime don't have a recognizable symbol, but rather  a character's silhouette, like in case of Mushishi, so I doubt it would be easy to find something from them to fit into 40 pixels or less.

Here are my lists, but please post your own answer if you have something to add:

Some of the more iconic imagery:

- Death Note − [Ryuk's eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi8M4.jpg)
- [Naruto's forehead protector symbol](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Forehead_Protector)
- Full Metal Alchemist − [transmutation circles](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemy) (it's a huge thing, not sure it can be recognizable in small size)
- Pokemon − [pokeball](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Pokeball.PNG)
- Soul Eater − [Sun](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Sun), [Moon](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Moon), the [school principal's mask](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/File:Shinigami_s_Mask_by_LordDonovan.png) and [the symbol in its logo](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_Eater)
- One Piece [logo](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Jolly_Roger)
- TTGL − [Kamina's glasses](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Kamina) and [core drill necklace/key](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Core_Drill)
- Evangelion's [NERV leaf logo](https://wiki.evageeks.org/Nerv_Logo)
- Azumanga Daioh's ["a!" speech bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Azumanga_A!.svg) and [the papa cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXBQX.jpg)
- Madoka Magica's [soul gems](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Soul_gem#Soul_Gem) and [this fluffy pal](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Kyuubey)
- [Yotsuba to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsuba_Koiwai) − 4-leaf clover (which is coincidentally also a 4chan logo but it's as much the manga's most iconic symbol also)
- [Kobayashi-san chi no Maid Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Kobayashi%27s_Dragon_Maid) − [Toohru's horns as seen in the logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtoR5.jpg)
- FLCL − ["tv robot head"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2USI.jpg)
- Kill la Kill − [school uniform scarf/eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWBEx.png) (the opposite of where the arrow is pointing) and the iconic [scissor blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71IZa.jpg)
- Bakemonogatari − [Araragi's unkempt hair patch](https://38.media.tumblr.com/2dced8f25cac6953b4e5916e92faa3ba/tumblr_naex3rlPQW1s5f9ado1_500.gif), [Tsukihi's sunny side up hairpin](http://bakemonogatari.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukihi_Araragi)
- One Punch Man − [Saitama's comically simplistic, yet very recognizable facial features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijIZ.jpg)
- Cowboy Bebop − [smiley face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BOZ1.jpg)
- Ghost in the Shell − [laughing man logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEYH1.jpg)
- Durarara's [unmistakable bike helmet with cat ears](http://durarara.wikia.com/wiki/Celty_Sturluson) which you can buy on ebay
- Nisekoi's [locket with mysterious contents](http://nisekoi.wikia.com/wiki/Raku_Ichij%C5%8D)
- Paranoia Agent's [bent bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc2IH.jpg) which is on the front cover artwork
- Totoro's face and silhouette which is also part of studio Ghibli's logo
- Hellsing's [longest-barreled gun](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Hellsing_Ultimate)
- Psycho-Pass's [gun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr7hG.png)
- Spirited Away's [No-Face mask](http://spiritedaway.wikia.com/wiki/No-Face_(Kaonashi))
- Hanayamata's Yosakoi dance [clapper Naruko](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl8Gp.jpg)
- Natsume Yuujinchou − [Nyanko-sensei's cheeky smile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u6Nk.jpg)
- Nichijou − [a lil yellow bird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDJxw.png) (peep-peep)

Our chat room in-jokes:

- Tomato − because [Toshinou Kyouko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1530/toshinou-kyouko) is [a tomato](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbYEt.jpg)
- [Taisho aka Sakamoto](http://nichijou.wikia.com/wiki/Sakamoto) − our chat bot, but also a recognizable character from Nichijou

Generic anime/Japan themed things:

- a schoolgirl biting a toast running late to school
- Sakura petals
- sushi roll
- rice triangle
- bento box with chopsticks on top
- cicadas definitely
- samurais, ronins and ninjas, which are also prominent in many anime, and so are their katanas, headbands and throwing knives, stars, shurikens, kunais
- daruma doll
- kotatsu
- vending machines with countless varieties of tea, black coffee and unusually flavored drinks
- shaved ice
- teru-teru boozu doll ("rain pls stop" charm)
- watermelon being smashed with a stick (a popular and tasty summer entertainment as we've been led to believe, from the countless beach episodes)

Comment: I kind of have this gut feeling, given [this](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4050/my-post-was-removed-due-to-dmca-takedown-notice-what-can-i-do), that perhaps it should be limited to original artwork and public domain imagery, at minimum to reduce potential complications in the long run. Plus original user-submitted artwork would give it a cool community vibe.

Comment: @JasonC I'm pretty sure it's okay to do a mashup of intellectual property imagery in this manner, as the Movies.SE has had their header film strip with all the iconic characters and scenes for such a long time without any problems.

Comment: @JasonC additionally, I've tried calling for the community to post their own artwork for years, and there was basically no response.

Comment: there countless japan theme things that are pretty iconic. like their trains/train stations, quaint shophouses, summer cicadas, clogs, samurai/ninjas....

Comment: @Tyhja just add your answer, it's good info

Comment: As well as Sakamoto, there's the cute little bird from Nichijou too

Comment: I guess we're doing comments instead of answers! btw hop into chat someteims

Comment: I vote for some Ohmu from _Nausicaa_ and the bike from _Akira_.

Comment: we also have [this logo](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/459/2869)

Comment: also, the list lack of shoujo demographic, probably we can use something from sailormoon or cardcaptor sakura

Comment: for FMA, they also have [homunculus logo](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/fma/images/0/0c/Ouroboros_Tatoo.JPG). It seems more recognizable in small size

Comment: @Darjeeling you'll have to give specific examples from shoujo genre coz maybe I haven't been paying attention but I don't know any recognizable symbols from there

Comment: not really sure about Sailor Moon but Cardcaptor Sakura have [these wands/keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPkFw.png)