# Happy Holidays, Anime & Manga SE Community!

Tags: discussion

Yet another year has passed, and the season of festivity is once again upon us.
This year around a lot has happened in our community once again, and as a community, we should celebrate the good.

One of the big things that happened this year, is the site design. It was a turbulent road, where the first design was not really to the tastes of most: [Anime & Manga Site Design](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4245/1458) .
And even though this was meant to be final, our designated community manager, [@JNat](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/jnat) went the extra mile, and got all of us yet another design.
[Anime & Manga Site Design — June update](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4264/1458)
Which ended up with us getting a great design, as we can see on the site these days.

Therefore on behalf of the whole community, we would like to extend our thanks. [@JNat](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/jnat) thank you for all the efforts you put in, and below you will find your tracking code for the 3rd part of your gift.

https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item#/tracking-results/LZ634565250US

Of course this all wouldn’t have been possible without the community itself either, which throughout the years have kept asking and answering questions, and helping new people find their twist on the platform. So we would also like to extend our gratitude to the whole community as well, let's make it another great year on A&M where people can learn more about anime and manga.

And last, but definitely not least, I would personally like to extend a special thanks to [@кяαzєя](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63/%d0%ba%d1%8f%ce%b1z%d1%94%d1%8f), as without their effort, the gift coordination would not have been possible.

So on behalf of the moderation team, we would like to wish everyone in the community a very happy holiday, and a soon to come, great new year!

If you wish to leave your thanks or well-wishes to anyone within the community or in general, please feel free to leave a holiday cheer or call-out in the answers. Thru happy times and sad tidings the community would not be what it is without the contributions of every one. No matter how big, no matter how small. Every bit matters. Cheers to everyone.

Happy holidays and well-wishes in the coming year!

[image: Argonauts assemble!]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took me a while to go pick it up with the holidays and all, I know, but I picked up this awesome Ukiyo-e styled Megaman illustration from the SE London office earlier this week:

[image: Ukiyo-e styled Megaman illustration]

In addition to that, in late December I'd also received two CDs, shipped from Japan, with Megaman 1 and 2's soundtracks, courtesy of [кяαzєя](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63/%d0%ba%d1%8f%ce%b1z%d1%94%d1%8f), [Killua](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/274/killua), and members of the community, past and present!

It's really amazing that y'all coordinated to send this my way, and it took me completely by surprise — I've been working for you all since 2012, and I do so not expecting anything in return. It's been a journey, and one that I'm glad to have been a part of since the site's private beta.

As [Dimitri mx](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1458/dimitri-mx) noted in the original post, none of this would've been possible without you all — so **thank you, sincerely, for working on this community day after day.**

Now all I need to do is find a decent frame, and hang this on my wall! ^_^