# 2014 Edition: What should we call our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Now that we've made it past the one year mark, lets take sometime and consider if we should have a fancier name for our [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/).

The [previous post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/what-should-we-call-our-chat-room) from over a year ago favored, the generic "Anime and Manga Chat" name as the name. I personally think we should come up with something unique like what the other SE sites have done, but I'll leave the ultimate decision up to the community. Do we want a (cool) new name for our main chat room?

If you're interested in proposing a new name, post a answer to this question that includes:

- The suggested **name** (possibly explain why that name).
- A **description** of the room (feel free to add any tags you feel are relevant -- it doesn't matter if they currently exist or not).
- An **explanation** is optional, but it will help other understand your intent.

As ["A" wise person](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15/alenanno) once said:

> In any case, provide one per answer, so other people can vote on a single proposal. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've mentioned this several times in the chat. But to make it official:

How about: [**"The Maid Cafe"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maid_caf%C3%A9)

It's not very original, but:

- It's short.
- Easy to remember.
- Representative of the culture.
- Has a fairly minimal risk of offending anybody.

I don't have any ideas for a description though. Feel free to make a suggestion.

Comment: [(The) Maids, (Have) Arrived!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zojY06rkfdY).

Comment: So, you will be a maid?

Comment: @Abyx http://i.stack.imgur.com/5mC9a.jpg - No. We're just the customers.

Comment: I see. But it would be boring without maids.

Comment: Btw there is another trope - "a haunted house". Since the room looks so empty.

Comment: Call it _The Doge Cafe_.

Comment: @iKlsR What's a "Doge cafe"?

Comment: @Mysticial err.. a tasty beverage? I know they have hot doges.

Comment: A description could be "Serving the Anime/Manga Dream"

Comment: ^Extended "Serving the Anime/Manga Dream every Weeknight, BYO Loli"

Comment: I like that first one, "Serving the Anime/Manga Dream". :) Could also be, "Serving the Otaku Dream". But Anime/Manga is more recognizable.

Comment: @Mysticial i was going to do Otaku but yeh, for the same reason you mentioned, Anime/Manga is more recognizable

Answer (score 1):

**Name:** MADHouse (**M**anga and **A**nime **D**iscussion **House**)

**Description:** Your one-stop studio for parodying and reliving as your favorite anime/manga characters. Y U NO MAD?

**References:**

- [Madhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhouse_%28company%29)
- [MAD](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/mad)
- [Y U NO](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/y-u-no-guy)
- [Yuno](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSQRb.png)
- [nomad](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nomad)

Comment: See the [relevant chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21504387#21504387) that prompted my making a new nomination.

Answer (score 1):

**Name**: Ahnenerbe Cafe

**Reference**:

- "A coffee shop used as a location for TYPE-MOON metafiction, involving the Fate, Tsukihime, and Kara no Kyoukai worlds." -- from [Type Moon Wiki](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ahnenerbe).

Comment: I like this, but I looked up "Ahnenerbe" and got a Nazi research institute, for what it's worth...

Comment: @Maroon: Yes, it is also mentioned in the Type Moon Wiki. Might be a problem if people don't get the reference.

Answer (score -1):

**Name:** Anime & Manga Chat

**Description:** General discussion for anime.stackexchange.com. Discuss your favorite character, theories, and series. Ask or give recommendations. Nothing related to the subject of anime and manga is off-topic here.

---

This is the current name/description of the chatroom. Upvote (or downvote) this post if you want (resp. don't want) to keep the chatroom name/description the same.

Comment: I'm downvoting because this makes the chat and main site tabs indistinguishable without the mouseover text: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YTu7L.png. I wouldn't be opposed to a similar name that is distinct from the main site name though.

Comment: @LoganM Very good point. If it matters, imagine that I have downvoted this post too, because that really is kind of annoying now that you mention it.